# A potential memory overflow but not sure what's causing it

Tags: c, embedded, freertos

I am seeing a potential overflow: `streamBuffer` is a struct object (part of the FreeRTOS lib) and upon executing the following line in `OutputToSerial()`, I see `streamBuffer.xHead`'s value is set to an extremely large value even though it's not being modified at the time.

```
LONG_TO_STR(strData, txStr);
```

- Note that I didn't have any issues when I called `nRF24_ReadReg()` multiple times before.
- Also, often times I see that `printf` doesn't print the entire text that's being printed (prior to calling the time when I see a potential overflow) - instead misses on some chars.

Any way to get a better understanding of the cause? I don't see any hardfaults or anything to look in the registers...

For a reference, the following is the struct's definition:

```
typedef struct StreamBufferDef_t /*lint !e9058 Style convention uses tag. */
{
    volatile size_t xTail;              /* Index to the next item to read within the buffer. */
    volatile size_t xHead;              /* Index to the next item to write within the buffer. */

    size_t xLength;                     /* The length of the buffer pointed to by pucBuffer. */
    size_t xTriggerLevelBytes;          /* The number of bytes that must be in the stream buffer before a task that is waiting for data is unblocked. */
    volatile TaskHandle_t xTaskWaitingToReceive; /* Holds the handle of a task waiting for data, or NULL if no tasks are waiting. */
    volatile TaskHandle_t xTaskWaitingToSend;   /* Holds the handle of a task waiting to send data to a message buffer that is full. */
    uint8_t *pucBuffer;                 /* Points to the buffer itself - that is - the RAM that stores the data passed through the buffer. */
    uint8_t ucFlags;

    #if ( configUSE_TRACE_FACILITY == 1 )
        UBaseType_t uxStreamBufferNumber;       /* Used for tracing purposes. */
    #endif
} StreamBuffer_t;
```

```
// file.c
#define PRI_UINT64_C_Val(value) ((unsigned long) (value>>32)), ((unsigned long)value)
#define LONG_TO_STR(STR, LONG_VAL) (sprintf(STR, "%lx%lx", PRI_UINT64_C_Val(LONG_VAL)))

unsigned long long concatData(uint8_t *arr, uint8_t size)
{
    long long unsigned value = 0;
    for (uint8_t i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        value <<= 8;
        value |= arr[i];
    }
    return value;
}

void nRF24_ReadReg(nrfl2401 *nrf, uint8_t reg, const uint8_t rxSize, uint8_t *rxBuffer, char *text)
{
    uint8_t txBuffer[1] = {0};
    uint8_t spiRxSize = rxSize;

    if (reg <= nRF24_CMD_W_REG)
    {
        txBuffer[0] = nRF24_CMD_R_REG | (reg & nRF24_R_W_MASK);
        spiRxSize++;
    }
    else
    {
        txBuffer[0] = reg;
    }

    nRF24_SendCommand(nrf, txBuffer, rxBuffer, spiRxSize);

    OutputToSerial(txBuffer, rxBuffer, spiRxSize, text);
}

void OutputToSerial(uint8_t *writeBuffer, uint8_t *readBuffer, uint8_t size, char *text)
{
    char strData[100] = {0}, rxStrData[100] = {0};
    long long unsigned txStr = concatData(writeBuffer, size);
    long long unsigned rxStr = concatData(readBuffer, size);
    LONG_TO_STR(strData, txStr);              // POTENTIAL ERROR.....!
    LONG_TO_STR(rxStrData, rxStr);

    char outputMsg[60] = {0};
    strcpy(outputMsg, text);
    strcat(outputMsg, ":          0x%s ----------- 0x%s\n");

    printf (outputMsg, strData, rxStrData);
}

// main.c
StreamBufferHandle_t streamBuffer;
```

Comment: I got the hint from: https://github.com/SuperHouse/esp-open-rtos/issues/116

Comment: `"%lx%lx"` makes more sense as `"%lx%08lx"`.  Curious, why not print with `"%llx"`?

Comment: `LONG_TO_STR(STR, LONG_VAL)` better named as `UNSIGNED_LONG_LONG_TO_STR(STR, ULLONG_VAL)`

Comment: `%llx` just prints `lx`

Comment: What compiler are you  using that has `long long`, yet does not understand `"%llx"`?

Comment: gcc. you can find the same issue in the github link I posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps other issues, yet the `LONG_TO_STR(x)` is simply a mess.
Consider the value `0x123400005678` would print as `"12345678"`.  That [ref code](https://github.com/SuperHouse/esp-open-rtos/issues/116) is broken.

Yes its too bad code has `long long` yet no `"%llx"`.  Easy enough to re-write it all into a clean function.

```
//#define PRI_UINT64_C_Val(value) ((unsigned long) (value>>32)), ((unsigned long)value)
//#define LONG_TO_STR(STR, LONG_VAL) (sprintf(STR, "%lx%lx", PRI_UINT64_C_Val(LONG_VAL)))

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <limits.h>

// Good for base [2...16]
void ullong_to_string(char *dest, unsigned long long x, int base) {
  char buf[sizeof x * CHAR_BIT + 1]; // Worst case size
  char *p = &buf[sizeof buf - 1];  // set to last element
  *p = '\0';
  do {
    p--;
    *p = "0123456789ABCDEF"[x % (unsigned) base];
    x /= (unsigned) base;
  } while (x);
  strcpy(dest, p);
}

int main(void) {
  char buf[100];
  ullong_to_string(buf, 0x123400005678, 16);   puts(buf);
  ullong_to_string(buf, 0, 16);   puts(buf);
  ullong_to_string(buf, ULLONG_MAX, 16);   puts(buf);
  ullong_to_string(buf, ULLONG_MAX, 10);   puts(buf);
  return 0;
}
```

Output

```
123400005678
0
FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
18446744073709551615
```

Comment: okay i'm trying to make sense of your logic. what's `"0123456789ABCDEF"[x %(unsigned)base];`?

Comment: @Jarj `x %(unsigned)base` gets the least significant hex digit of `x`.  That value indexes the string `"0123456789ABCDEF"` to translated that value into  its representative digit character.

Comment: what's the idea behind `"0123456789ABCDEF"` and indexing? you're also missing the `&` upon initializing `char *p`. I tried running it but doesn't seem like it's working. or maybe i'm misinterpreting it

Comment: @Jarj Tidied up code.  Example: `"0123456789ABCDEF"` is a string.  Indexing the 12th character with `"0123456789ABCDEF"[12]` results in the `char` `'C'` to assign to `*p`.